# xpath google sheet importxml

Tags: xml, google-sheets, web-scraping, xpath, yahoo-finance

this is the link i want to do my importxml on

https://sg.finance.yahoo.com/quote/D05.SI

```
<div class="dot-label Pos(r) Fz(13px) Fw(500) D(ib) Ta(c)"><span>Current</span><!-- react-text: 18 -->&nbsp;<!-- /react-text --><span>25.08</span></div>
```

i would like to use importxml to retrieve the value 25.08.

```
=IMPORTXML("https://sg.finance.yahoo.com/quote/D05.SI","//*[@class='dot-label Pos(r) Fz(13px) Fw(500) D(ib) Ta(c)']//span")
```

but it always return #NA, please advise the correct syntax or link and the reasons so i can have some understanding.

Comment: Which value you want to retrieve? Since it is dynamic class, the `class` attribute changes anytime, you need to use another scraping technique to retrieve the data.

Comment: i need to retrieve the current price. can you advise the name of another scaping technique and method?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Scraping data to Google Sheets from a website that uses JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74237688/scraping-data-to-google-sheets-from-a-website-that-uses-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

Using `id` attribute selector is always safer than using `class` attribute selector, because they are using class binding and it gets changed frequently. I found the closest DOM that has `id` attribute, and lookup until the current price is scraped.

[image]

You should try this xpath:

```
=INDEX(IMPORTXML("https://sg.finance.yahoo.com/quote/D05.SI","//div[@id='quote-header-info']/div[last()]/div[1]"),1)
```

But sometimes the layout / DOM structure get changed, you might need to check and update the xpath to ensure that it correctly scrape the value that you wanted.

Comment: wow, it worked perfectly but i dont quite understood the code.

may i know the purpose of using Index?

also div[last()] is to get the last div of @id='quote-header-info' am i right? is there any link which has all documentation on these syntax? for the last(), first()? how many more are there? 

for div[1] it worked like an array? but start with 1 instead of 0?

how did the code reaches the span class and retrieve the text?

Comment: For div[last()], it selects the last child of the div[@id='quote-header-info']. For div[1], it starts with 1 and meaning the first child. And it has several matched values returned for the given xpath, the first value is which we are interested.